# Python-pptx: Adding a notes slide causes PowerPoint 2013 to crash

Tags: python-pptx

I have a script containing something similar to the stripped-down code below. The purpose is to add a notes slide (and text) below an ordinary slide. It works perfectly fine on a system with PowerPoint 2007 installed.

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()

title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]

title_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = title_slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Title"

blank_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
notes_slide = blank_slide.notes_slide
notes_slide.notes_text_frame.text = "foo"

prs.save('example.pptx')
```

Unfortunately, when using PowerPoint 2013 (with Windows 7): the code runs without error, but when I attempt to open the PowerPoint presentation I receive notification that 'Microsoft PowerPoint has stopped working'. This error is fixed when the two notes_slide lines within the above code are removed (i.e. there's nothing else in my code that is causing the issue).

Can anyone provide enlightenment on what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have a solution to my own question, but I am not too satisfied with the work-around.

It turns out that for PowerPoint 2013, if you want to add a notes slide to one or more slides, you must add a notes slide (with no text) to *every* other slide, otherwise PowerPoint 2013 will crash.

```
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()

title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]

title_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = title_slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Title"

notes_slide = title_slide.notes_slide #The only new line of code

blank_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
notes_slide = blank_slide.notes_slide
notes_slide.notes_text_frame.text = "foo"

prs.save('example.pptx')
```

Has anyone had a different experience?

Comment: This is a very interesting behavior @cthomas. Can you point me to where you saw that all slides must have a notes slide in PowerPoint 2013 and later? That seems a little odd, because there are plenty of .pptx files created with 2007 that don't have them for every slide, and it seems to load those just fine.

Comment: Hi scanny, I didn't see it anywhere on the web - I just modified the code until I got it working. Basically I was able to create working .pptx files only if there were no notes slides at all, or every slide had a notes slide. Otherwise the .pptx file caused PowerPoint 2013 to crash. Indeed, it seems perfectly okay not to add a notes slide to every slide in PowerPoint 2007. I haven't tried PowerPoint 2010. Is there any more information I can provide to help clear up the issue?

Comment: Probably makes sense to open up an issue for it on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues, maybe something like "PowerPoint 2010 Notes Page behavior". Then we can have a longer conversation about it. I think a few experiments are in order, like creating a new 2010 pptx with three blank slides, add notes to slide 2, see what the package contains as far as notesSlide objects, etc. I expect that will narrow down the specific problem pretty quickly.